# How to set up svn+ssh for several users?

Tags: svn, ssh

How to set up an SVN repository on a linux server that one can only access via SVN+SSH? There should be different users, all of which should just be able to use the SVN, so they are not supposed to log into the server and SVN without SSH should be prohibited.

Comment: Just as a comment why I've provided the question and answer: There are so many tutorials that look good and correct at first glance, but they are often pair-wise contradictory and at least incomplete. There does not seem to be any simple-to-follow step-by-step instruction that actually works. So, I wanted to give a brief but complete step-by-step description that would have saved me *an immense* amount of time.

Comment: The close vote, and probably also the downvote, is because this is off-topic. It should go on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/), I think. Self-answering a question is accepted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To be sure that everything really works, I was following these exact instructions on an ubuntu 14.04 server (for hosting) with Subversion command-line client, version 1.8.8 and an ubuntu 16.04 laptop (for using the SVN). [Much later I've tested/confirmed this with an Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS server and client (i.e., both computers had the same current OS).]

**Step 1:** Defining the users.

Let's assume we have two different users that are going to use the SVN. We will have to define local accounts for these users on the machine to be able to put them into a common group. This is required to grant the group write access to the repository, as otherwise committing does not work. We will also see how to prevent these users from logging into the server (since we only want them as SVN users; the local accounts are just an unavoidable means for this purpose).
Since svn+ssh requires SSH login, we need an additional user that is used to connect to the machine. So, we have:

```
USER-1 (to access SVN)
USER-2 (to access SVN)
SSH-USER (to connect to the server)
SVN-GROUP (a group with members USER-1 and USER-2)
```

In commands, that is:

```
adduser USER-1
adduser USER-2
adduser SSH-USER
groupadd SVN-GROUP
sudo usermod -aG SVN-GROUP USER-1
sudo usermod -aG SVN-GROUP USER-2
```

To check whether everything is right, you can list the groups and their members (as mentioned in [How to list all users in a Linux group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835368/how-to-list-all-users-in-a-linux-group) -- like that answer/response if you find it useful) via:

```
awk -F: '/^SVN-GROUP/ {print $4;}' /etc/group
```

**Step 2:** Create the SVN and fill it with content.

First, we log into the server with the user that is used to log into the server, SSH-USER. Then, we create an empty folder for the SVN, then fill it with an empty SVN, then set the rights so that everyone in the group has full access.

```
mkdir /home/SSH-USER/SVN
svnadmin create /home/SSH-USER/SVN
chgrp -R SVN-GROUP /home/SSH-USER/SVN
chown -R SSH-USER /home/SSH-USER/SVN
chmod -R 770 /home/SSH-USER/SVN
```

The last two commands take all rights from "others" and give read/write/execute rights to the owner (SSH-USER) and the group (SVN-GROUP). I have tested it: using just read/write rights is not sufficient. However, we could give 0 (no rights) to the owner, since we only need him to login, not to commit or read or anything. However, if we want to delete the entire SVN with that user, we should not steal his rights.

We can now already fill it with content despite not having configured the access control yet. The reason for this is that the local user SSH-USER can directly commit changes even if the SVNs access configuration (which we did not touch yet) does prohibit it. We add just two empty folders:

```
 svn mkdir file:///home/SSH-USER/SVN/folder1
 svn mkdir file:///home/SSH-USER/SVN/folder2
```

**Step 3:** configure the SVN access control(s).

First, we edit the the "main configuration file" of the SVN: /home/SSH-USER/SVN/conf/svnserve.conf. Here, make sure that the file contains the following three lines:

```
anon-access = none
auth-access = write
authz-db = authz
```

A few notes: all three lines are already present in the file, but commented out. The first line, however, grants anonymous ready access by default, so we change it from "read" to "none". Further, in most instructions one is asked to uncomment the line "# password-db = passwd". We do not need this, however, because we only grant SVN+SSH access, so the passwords are not used.

Having activated the authentification file authz, we now use it to set up which user gets which access to which folder. So, make sure the file authz contains the following lines:

```
[groups]
SVN-GROUP = USER-1,USER-2
[/]
* =
@SVN-GROUP = rw
```

First, note that the group name used in the authz file is just chosen in the same way than our group on the server for consistency. You can choose any group name you want. The users, on the other side, *have* to be the same than the local users on the server. According to the definition above, both users have full access to the entire repository and no other users have any access. One can add more specific rights by simply adding more content, e.g.:

```
[/folder1]
USER-1 = rw
USER-2 = 
[/folder2]
USER-1 = 
USER-2 = rw
```

**Step 4:** Setup the access to the server.

First, we need to create a folder ".ssh" and then add the public SSH keys for all users that want to access the SVN. The individual users will, however, not login with their individual accounts, but they will use the account of the user SSH-USER. That way, we have one single file that manages the access. When one of the users logs in (using the account of SSH-USER), then the ssh access file will change that user to the respective local user.

```
mkdir /home/SSH-USER/.ssh
touch /home/SSH-USER/.ssh/authorized_keys
nano /home/SSH-USER/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Now fill authorized_keys with the following content:

```
command="svnserve -t -r /home/SSH-USER --log-file=/home/SSH-USER/SVN/svnlog.txt --tunnel-user=USER-1 --config-file=/home/SSH-USER/SVN/conf/svnserve.conf" ssh-rsa PUBLIC-KEY-OF-USER-1 local-username-on@client-pc-of-USER-1
command="svnserve -t -r /home/SSH-USER --log-file=/home/SSH-USER/SVN/svnlog.txt --tunnel-user=USER-2 --config-file=/home/SSH-USER/SVN/conf/svnserve.conf" ssh-rsa PUBLIC-KEY-OF-USER-2 local-username-on@client-pc-of-USER-2
```

For users who are not familiar with authorized_keys files note that local-username-on@client-pc-of-USER-i is just a label to manage/label different entries (i.e, user names and machines), so the "information" put here cannot be wrong. Further, PUBLIC-KEY-OF-USER-i is the actual key, i.e., that very long String found in the respective public key file of that user.

Now, both users can access the SVN using the following command: "svn checkout svn+ssh://SSH-USER@SERVER-URL/SVN .". Note that, due to the previously set restrictions, USER-1 can only access folder1 and USER-2 can only access folder2. Further, since the svnserve command defines /home/SSH-USER as the root of the SVN, the checkout command does not need to (or is allowed to) use the full path, but just everything after /home/SSH-USER (i.e., the folder needs to start with /SVN).

**Step 5:** Fine-tuning (optional).

There are a few optional, but convenient things one would still like to do:

(1) Give less rights to USER-1 and USER-2.
(2) Do not allow USER-1 and USER-2 to login via SSH on the server.
(3) Allow SSH login for SSH-USER (for configuration purposes).

(1)
For most tutorials/etc. that I found, it was recommended to add "no-port-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-pty" to the access control to restrict the respective rights. Please search by yourself, what they are restricting. Then, the authorized_keys file will look as follows:

```
command="svnserve -t -r /home/SSH-USER --log-file=/home/SSH-USER/SVN/svnlog.txt --tunnel-user=USER-1 --config-file=/home/SSH-USER/SVN/conf/svnserve.conf",no-port-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-pty ssh-rsa PUBLIC-KEY-OF-USER-1 local-username-on@client-pc-of-USER-1
command="svnserve -t -r /home/SSH-USER --log-file=/home/SSH-USER/SVN/svnlog.txt --tunnel-user=USER-2 --config-file=/home/SSH-USER/SVN/conf/svnserve.conf",no-port-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-pty ssh-rsa PUBLIC-KEY-OF-USER-2 local-username-on@client-pc-of-USER-2
```

(2)
We had to create the local users USER-1 and USER-2 so they are able to get write access to the repository. However, we do not want them to be able to connect to the server (to run programs, etc.). Of course, we could just not tell them their password, but apparently there seems to be a nicer way. For this, consider the question https://serverfault.com/questions/538915/prevent-user-access-to-console-but-still-allow-svnssh-access-to-svn-repos.

(3)
All of the SSH keys used in the authorized_keys file can not be used to login as SSH-USER via SSH anymore, because the the svnserve command is executed upon login, which prevents one from using the console. So, in case one does still want to be able to login as SSH-USER, one needs to login relying on a different SSH key (and put it into the authorized_keys file using just the expression "ssh-rsa PUBLIC-KEY local-username-on@client-pc"). In case PUBLIC-KEY is already in use in that file (e.g., because one wants to login either as USER-1 or USER-2 (to use the repository) AND as SSH-USER for configuration), one needs to create a second SSH key and tell the console that is supposed to use this one for SSH instead of the other one that is already in use for SVN+SSH (for redirection to either USER-1 or USER-2). A nice solution to this is given here: [how to login via ssh if "svnserve -t" is given in authorized_keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41307767/how-to-login-via-ssh-if-svnserve-t-is-given-in-authorized-keys)

Comment: Great writeup thanks, would you know if the svn commits will now show up with SSH_USER or with USER1, USER2 if one follows this approach?

Comment: No, I am sorry, I have no idea anymore about this. I had to re-do all of this to see what happens.

Comment: I've finally "used" this again, so I can also answer the question: It shows the names of the individual users, *not* SSH-USER.

Comment: *We had to create the local users USER-1 and USER-2 so they are able to get write access to the repository.* — no, we don't. They both access repository as *SSH-USER* and all the security is provided by svnserve running under that account. System users USER-1 and USER-2 are not used anywhere in this setup so they need not to be created.

Comment: svnbook also says: ***Instead** of creating a separate system account for each user, generate a public/private key pair for each person.*